# html onresizeend event, or equivalent way to detect end of resize

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I'm trying to detect when the `onresize` event ends in a browser. If I use the `onresize` event, in Firefox it seems to be fired only once, after the resize event ends, which is exactly what I want. But if I try in IE, the `onresize` event gets fired many times during the resize.

I also try the `onresizeend` event, advertised in MSDN. But it does not seem to get fired at all, neither in Firefox, nor in IE. I use the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        <!--
        function doLog(message)
        {
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "<br/>" + message;
        }
        
        function doResize()
        {
            doLog("plain resize");
        }

        function doResizeEnd()
        {
            doLog("resize end");
        }
        -->
        </script>
        <style>
        <!--
        #log {
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onresize="doResize();" onresizeend="doResizeEnd();">
        <div id="log"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why this does not work? Maybe the `onresizeend` event is not supported? In this case, how can I detect when the `resize` event has ended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN onresizeend()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536960(VS.85).aspx)

> Only content editable objects can be
>   included in a control selection. You
>   can make objects content editable by
>   setting the contentEditable property
>   to true or by placing the parent
>   document in design mode.

That explains why it's not firing for you.   I suspect you don't want to enable contentEditable, so why not set a timer.

```
var resizeTimer = 0;
function doResize()
{
    if (resizeTimer)
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

    resizeTimer = setTimeout(doResizeEnd, 500);
}
```

It's not perfect but hopefully will be good enough.

Comment: Was about to post the same :)

Comment: Good answer. Note that `clearTimeout(x)` does not in fact change the boolean value of x, which will therefore return true whether or not it has been cleared; `clearTimeout` can also be passed anything without error. `if (resizeTimer)` is therefore redundant here.