# hide the right content according to the screen width

Tags: jquery

when i using the following code in a file.

```
var width=jQuery(window).width();
    if(width<980){
        jQuery('.std .home-right').hide();
    }else{
     jQuery('.std .home-right').show();
     }
```

when i resize the window width less than 980px, the .std .home-right can't hide, when i resize the window width less than 980px to bigger than 980, the .std .home-right can't show. why?

Comment: Can you include your event handler code? How are you detecting window resize?

Comment: Are you calling this on the window resize event? Can you show where this code is being called from ?

Comment: i don't know how to detect window resize. thank you

Comment: what is .sid .home-right? If they are classes of same div, you can use one of those classes. else seperate them by a comma like  jQuery('.std , .home-right').hide();

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect when a window is resized using JavaScript ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/detect-when-a-window-is-resized-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to monitor the resize event.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();
  console.log(width);
  if (width < 500) {
    $('.std .home-right').hide();
  } else {
    $('.std .home-right').show();
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C2Kx9/

Comment: i using the code to ipad equipment,if the screen is 400x300, do the $('.std .home-right').hide(); ok?

Comment: If you are asking whether iOS devices can run javascript... then yes. However, bigger picture, it sounds like you are using this to detect mobile devices in order to optimize the display. If that is the case then use the solution from @Bowie

Answer (score 3):

For your case, instead of jquery, use width detection in stylesheet may be simpler :

Add the following in your css:

```
@media all and (min-width: 980px) {  .std .home-right { display:none; } }

@media all and (max-width: 979px) {   .std .home-right { display:block; } }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: does this is css3? what @media all and (min-width: 980px) is meaning?

Comment: yes, the media type supported in css3.
Take a look at this for reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Answer (score 0):

add `$(window)` to resize event, like this:

```
function setWidth(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width < 980){
        jQuery('.std .home-right').hide();
        console.log(1);
    } else {
        jQuery('.std .home-right').show();
        console.log(2);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setWidth();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    setWidth();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is ( hopefully on document ready ) just set the width of the browser. If you want it work whilst whilst resizing you would need to do something like this;

```
$( window ).resize( function () {

    var width = $( window ).width();

    if ( width < 980 ) {
        $( '.std .home-right' ).hide();
    } else {
        $( '.std .home-right' ).show();
    }

});
```

That will cause the browse to hide and show the required elements. But before you go ahead and just dump that code in, may I recommend having a look at this page first

> http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/throttle/

The resize event will generate many events, this is usually considered a bad thing.

Comment: i using the code to ipad equipment,if the screen is 400x300, do the $('.std .home-right').hide(); ok?

Answer (score 0):

You should write this code in the window resize function like this

```
$(window).resize(function () {
var width=jQuery(window).width();
    if(width<980){
        jQuery('.std .home-right').hide();
    }else{
     jQuery('.std .home-right').show();
     }
});
```

this may useful for you