# jQuery responsive setting width of div

Tags: jquery, css-float, responsive-design, viewport

I have created a jsFiddle for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/kinthof/QpjnV/3/

The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://skafte.dk/img/oel/carlsberg-pilsner-33cl-51x192.jpg" class="" title="Carlsberg Pilsner 33cl" alt="Carlsberg Pilsner 33cl" />
    <img src="http://skafte.dk/img/sodavand/faxe-kondi-25cl-54x192.jpg" class="" title="Faxe Kondi 25cl" alt="Faxe Kondi 25cl" />
    <img src="http://skafte.dk/img/sodavand/coca-cola-25cl-50x192.jpg" class="" title="Coca Cola 25cl" alt="Coca Cola 25cl" />
    <img src="http://skafte.dk/img/sodavand/frem-aeblemost-25cl-56x191.jpg" class="" title="Frem Æblemost 25cl" alt="Frem Æblemost 25cl" />
    <img src="http://skafte.dk/img/diverse/cocio-40cl-58x192.jpg" class="" title="Cocio 40cl" alt="Cocio 40cl" />
    <img src="http://skafte.dk/img/kildevand/aquador-50cl-54x191.jpg" class="" title="Aquador Kildevand 50cl" alt="Aquador Kildevand 50cl" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}
.image-container img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}
```

jQuery:

```
/* Finding the images width and setting the container to the sum of the widths. */
$('.image-container').each(function () {
    var width = 0;
    $(this).find('img').each(function () {
        width += $(this).width();
    })
    $(this).width(width + 'px');
});

/* Setting width to 100% if the width is larger than the viewport */
$('.image-container').each(function () {
    var vpWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var imageContainerWidth = $(this).width();
    var numberOfElements = 0;

    if (imageContainerWidth > vpWidth) {
        $(".image-container").width('100%');
    }
});
```

I want to center the floated images. This is done in the first part where I find the images width and set the container to the sum of the widths, which I then center with CSS.

The purpose next is that if the viewport is smaller than the width of the .image-container then the .image-containers width sets to 100%.

But this only happens when the page is reloaded/updated.

My question is: How can this be done "live", so the width changes as I minimize the window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect when a window is resized using JavaScript ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/detect-when-a-window-is-resized-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the dimensions of the images (I see them in the file names), it'd be more efficient to just pre-set the container width accordingly and center with CSS. Assuming that this is impossible for some reason, make sure to wait until after the images have loaded (not just document ready), to measure their widths.

Given the above, you can handle window's `resize` event:

```
function centerImages() {
    // center the images
}

//once the images have finished loading:
$(window).resize(centerImages);
centerImages();
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

```
$('.image-container').each(function(){
    var containerWidth=0;
    $(this).find('img').each(function(){containerWidth+=$(this).width();})
    $(this).width(containerWidth+'px');

    $(this).find('img').each(function () { 
        $(this).attr('style','');      
        $(this).width(Math.floor(($(this).width() / containerWidth) * 100) + '%');       
    });
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.image-container').each(function () {
        var containerWidth = $('.image-container').width();
        var resizeWidth = containerWidth;
        var resizeWhen = '350';
        var documentWidth = $(window).width();

        if (resizeWhen > documentWidth){
            $(this).width(100+'%');
        } else {
            $(this).width(resizeWidth);
        }
    });
});
```