# 2 <td> tags with different scrollbars

Tags: asp.net, html-table

I have a table with 2 td tags.Inside first  is a gridview  and in a second td are details about selected item from the gridview.I use Devexpress.How to make that every td has its own scrollbar?

Comment: Put a div inside each td. Have them have fixed sizes and add the appropriate overflow styles. As for Devexpress, frankly, I don't know about it but I guess it will let you hack the html markup, right?

Comment: I have already added the divs.How do you mean fix size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hacking your HTML like this:

```
<td>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll"></div>
</td>
```

Or better, in your css:

```
div.scrolling_div {width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;}
```

And then, in your html markup...

```
<td>
    <div class="scrolling_div"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: No prob. My pleasure.

Comment: Oh,and how to make grid and details resizeable when browser windows is resizing?

Comment: That could end in rapid death, but check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/detect-when-a-window-is-resized-using-javascript . Alternative: instead of using fixed sizes in px use them in percentages, like width: 40%.