# Detect window height change using jQuery

Tags: jquery, height

The website content is dynamic when the user scrolls down the page height changes. What I want is to detect (alert) the current size after each scroll.

Something like `$(window).resize()` didn't work for me...

Comment: Can you provide a simple JSFiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/detect-when-a-window-is-resized-using-javascript

Comment: can you try this alert($(window).height());

Comment: Please provide a minimal example / JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$( document ).scroll(function() {
    alert($( window ).height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){ // On load
    $('#div').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
    $('#div').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
    });
```