# How do i make a div that stretches vertically with parent height?

Tags: html, css

I have a blog with some content in it (divs). When i click a div a lightbox-like article appears. It has a transparent black container and on the middle an article. The container has position absolute , width and height auto top 0 and z-index over all content beneath
 Its all ok until i resize the window. The the content of the body, the one underneath the article, goes beneath it. i want to make the container resize and stretch to cover that content too. And also to be able to scroll. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height and width of the box using `vh` and `vw` units which are set in terms of the height and width of the window.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: That would make it 100% of the viewport height. Not the body height, which in this case is not fixed

Comment: it would only make it 100% of the viewport height if you used 100vh     it would help me give a better answer if you showed your code.

Comment: Looking at this,  I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve.  On chrome,  the modal div always covers the content even on window resize.

Comment: Resize it horizontally.

Comment: Horizontal size specified in `%` or `vw` will work.  For scrolling, you'll likely need to use javascript like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/detect-when-a-window-is-resized-using-javascript