# Date time format changes when browser viewport is being resize

Tags: javascript

*Scenario is:*

I have a displayed full live datetime in javascript including name of the day.
However that format consumes too much space when the viewport is being resized so my solution is to
change the format (make it shorter) if the screen size is smaller.

It goes like this:

When the user has a very wide screen I'd like to provide her/him the full datetime and day like this:

*"23:34:39 - October 3, 2019 - Thursday"*

When the user is using a tablet format should be:

*"23:34:39 - Oct 3, 2019 - Thu"*

And when the user is on mobile or older phones which has a very small screen, the format should be:

*"23:34:39 - 2019-10-03 - Thu"* of if the code detects even smaller screen I will remove the seconds.

I have found several threads here about rezise(function()); [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/detect-when-a-window-is-resized-using-javascript) and addEventListener [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event) also another one [here](https://techstacker.com/javascript-detect-if-screen-width-is-greater-or-less-than/XXjho5wLJdLzFNDpT) so I have done some modification in my code but I can't seem to make it work, there is no display at all after I added the addEventListener.

here is my **jsclock.js**

```
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").matches) {
        function date_time(id) {

        date = new Date;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
        d = date.getDate();
        day = date.getDay();
        days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
        h = date.getHours();
        if(h<10)
        {
                h = "0"+h;
        }
        m = date.getMinutes();
        if(m<10)
        {
                m = "0"+m;
        }
        s = date.getSeconds();
        if(s<10)
        {
                s = "0"+s;
        }
        result = ''+h+':'+m+':'+s+' &nbsp; &#10070; &nbsp; '+months[month]+' '+d+', ' +year+' &nbsp; &#10070; &nbsp;  '+days[day]+'';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
        setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
        return true;
}
    } else if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)").matches) {
        function date_time(id) {

        date = new Date;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        months = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
        d = date.getDate();
        day = date.getDay();
        days = new Array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
        h = date.getHours();
        if(h<10)
        {
                h = "0"+h;
        }
        m = date.getMinutes();
        if(m<10)
        {
                m = "0"+m;
        }
        s = date.getSeconds();
        if(s<10)
        {
                s = "0"+s;
        }
        result = ''+h+':'+m+':'+s+' &nbsp; &#10070; &nbsp; '+months[month]+' '+d+', ' +year+' &nbsp; &#10070; &nbsp;  '+days[day]+'';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
        setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
        return true;
}
    } else (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 200px)").matches) {
        function date_time(id) {

        date = new Date;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        months = new Array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12');
        d = date.getDate();
        if(d<10)
        {
                d = "0"+d;
        }
        day = date.getDay();
        days = new Array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
        h = date.getHours();
        if(h<10)
        {
                h = "0"+h;
        }
        m = date.getMinutes();
        if(m<10)
        {
                m = "0"+m;
        }
        s = date.getSeconds();
        if(s<10)
        {
                s = "0"+s;
        }
        result = ''+h+':'+m+':'+s+' &nbsp; &#10070; &nbsp; ' +year+'-'+months[month]+'-'+d+'  &nbsp; &#10070; &nbsp;  '+days[day]+'';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
        setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
        return true;
}
    }
```

and how I'm displaying it.

```
span id="date_time"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = date_time('date_time');</script>
```

Comment: side comment: `23:34:39 - 2019-10-03 - Thu` takes up just as much space as `23:34:39 - Oct 3, 2019 - Thu`, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to make that replacement happen. Drop the seconds and the day?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , I want to drop the seconds only on the smallest screen available but if the user has a wide screen I want to provide everything including seconds and day.. I will squeeze as much details as possible to provide the user depending on the user's viewport size.

Comment: sure, but that just makes it even more important to use a different string. Pick your breakpoint widths, then for each breakpoint figure out which level of detailed text works (and possibly consider something like bootstrap, which can do a lot of that management for you, even, where you mark elements with classes like `col-sm`, `col-m`, `col-l`, etc. and it just does the hiding/revealing automatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the HTML for all the timestamps:

```
<span class="size-l date-time">nice and long datetimestamp<span>
<span class="size-m date-time">shorter datetimestamp<span>
<span class="size-s date-time">shortstamp</span>
```

and then hide them by default using CSS, with media queries that unhide whichever needs to be unhidden. There is no reason to use JS here at all:

```
.date-time { display: none; }

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
 .size-s .date-time { display: inline-block; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
 .size-m .date-time { display: inline-block; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
 .size-l .date-time { display: inline-block; }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work.. It displays nothing while I'm resizing the browser "However" your answer gave me a lot of idea.. so what I did is I removed the .date-time class because the "display: none" property makes it invisible. what I retain are those .size-* classes and for every media queries I put all three of them and just put "display: inline" to the class I wanted to appear and "display: none" to the rest.

Comment: still voting up because of the idea you gave me.. thank you Sir. I'ts working now just as what I wanted :)